# pc hang at motherboard's splash screen

Tags: motherboard, post

last night my pc was working normally. Today when I power on my pc it just hangs at motherboard's logo screen. The keyboard was working slowly (when I press num lock key the light indicator works after 5 seconds).

I was not able to go in the BIOSs also. Normally my motherboard(intel DG41ty) gives two beeps at 3 second interval when it starts, but today it gives only one beep and just hangs. When I press the power button on the cabinet it turns off instantly.

This happens 5-6 times then after that pc is running perfectly. Nothing recorded in BIOS event. I want to know what the problem was.

Comment: AMI BIOS beep codes 1 short (DRAM refresh failure)http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm#04, i would download memtest86, http://www.memtest86.com/

Comment: +1 I have an Intel board (dp35dpm) and have observed the same behavior before. Usually a hard reboot puts things back to normal. No idea what it is though :/

Comment: @Aki actually in the case of this board beeps code are not like other boards because on most of other boards there is no beep at start when they run normally but two beeps at starting on this board is normal.